# How do I reload the theme .info file on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

How do I reload the theme .info file on Drupal 7?  I added the following line of code in order to add my own Javascript file to the pages:

```
scripts[] = myJavaScriptFile.js
```

Now I need to refresh the .info file somehow. It doesn't seem to be doing this on its own. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to [clear the theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176).

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush, enter

```
  drush cc all
```